# Unable to load DLL 'mclmcrrt9_4.dll'

Tags: c#, matlab, .net-assembly

I'm trying to integrate a Matlab .net assembly into a C# application with MWarray. I got the error:

> Unable to load DLL `mclmcrrt9_4.dll` when building the application

in visual studio.

I did copy all these dependencies like `mclmcrrt9_4.dll` from coworker's windowns machine to my macbook but don't know how to get them loaded in runtime.

Comment: Add a reference in your references in your project (if your using visual studio just right click on references and add)

Comment: @Brad I tried to add 'mclmcrrt9_4.dll' to my references but it says it's not a valid .Net assembly

Comment: Ok, I had similar issues with other .dlls but I am not familiar with matlab, maybe there is a different version you can try.

Answer (score -1):

There are a couple of things that you may need to look into:

- check system environment to make sure you have the right path
- make sure your project is set to the correct mclmcrrt version (check the app.config)